# Como redirecionar url do método GET com htaccess simples

Tags: php, htaccess, url, get, domínio

Bom dia, já procurei muito encontrei vários tutoriais mas to muito tempo sem mexer com programação. Eu preciso redirecionar meus urls enviado por GET.
Ex:
url atual: http://meuurl.com/w/index.php?l=Procurar

queria que ficasse assim:
 http://meuurl.com/procurar

se for necessário tirar a pasta /w/ pode ser eu acho que com htaccess da mas se tiver outro meio também!

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: me ajudem por favor!!

Comment: você pode configurar as rotas manualmente via htacess, ou você pode usar o Routing de algum framework como por exemplo do Symfony http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html